# window.location truncating URL with button onclick

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, window.location

When setting window.location with a button onclick event, the result is being truncated after the second parameter name.

This code:

```
<button onclick="window.location='index.php?p=reports_manage&id=new'">create new report - button</button>
```

Is sending the the user to this page:

```
https://foo.com/index.php?p=reports_manage&id=
```

Even if I add extra parameters at the end it still gets cut off at the same place.

All of these work fine however:

```
<a href="index.php?p=reports_manage&id=new">create new report - link</a>
<a href="javascript:window.location='index.php?p=reports_manage&id=new'">create new report - JS1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.location='index.php?p=reports_manage&id=new'">create new report - JS2</a>
```

Any idea what could be causing this? As far as I can tell the button was working fine earlier and broke without any change to this code. What else could be affecting this? There are no javascript errors on the page and it happens regardless of what browser is used.

Comment: [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/gthtB/)

Comment: Does the DOM inspector show the same as your HTML code or may there be a parse problem?

Comment: Have you tried using <input type="button" onclick="" /> instead of the button element? I recommend always using input for button as browser have different and sometimes unexpected behaviour for <button>

Comment: @Bergi The DOM inspector does show the correct code. However, when I hover over the button in IE it shows the truncated url at the bottom of the page. I'll look closely through everything else for any syntax errors or open quotes.

Comment: @gillesc using an input tag worked great here. Not sure why <button> didn't, but it's not too important. Can you enter that as a solution so I can credit you?

Comment: A long shot, but maybe specifying the button type will help. In this case type="button".

Comment: @trickyzter Your solution also worked. Using: `<button type="button" onclick="">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<input type="button" />` instead of `<button></button>` as it has unexpected behaviour (and if use to submit a form it will even submit its content!)

Comment: Thanks. I originally used <button> because there is already a form on the page and I didn't want them to get mixed at all, but it doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: It should also be fine to use `<button type="button">` as in @trickyzter's answer.

Answer (score 4):

A long shot, but maybe specifying the button type will help. In this case type="button".

@William: Different browsers have different pre-requisites, however as a safeguard it's always good to be explicit. ;)